# BooleanQuery between multiple fields

Tags: lucene, booleanquery

I have three fields say `F1`, `F2`, `F3`. I want to find all the documents which have all three fields values as null. Can I achieve this by using `BooleanQuery`? If I use `MUST_NOT` clause for all three fields then It will not return the documents which have one of these fields as non null value.

I'm talking about implementing something like this

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(F1,"")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(F2,"")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(F3,"")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
```

This surely is not going to work.How can i achieve this ? any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your index looks like but you wanna achieve this right?

you wanna have a query which is searching with this fields and this fields have to be empty

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(F1,"")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(F2,"")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(F3,"")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

This boolean query is searching for a empty terms (second param of term is "") in this field, for each field it has to be a must.